# Proof of an equality in Landau Notation

Tags: real-analysis

Definition 1: $\ g(h) = o(h) \quad {\rm iff} \quad g(h) = h \epsilon(h)$

where $\epsilon(h) \to 0$ as $h \to 0$

Definition 2: $\ g(h) = O(h) \quad {\rm iff} \quad \exists M > 0 \ {\rm such\ that} \ |g(h)| < Mh$

Show that if $g(h) = O(h^2)$ then $g(h) = o(h)$

I think my main difficulty comes from the fact that this notation is brand new to me. I've never worked with it before, and my professor only mentioned it briefly in his lectures. He thought we would have seen it before at some point, but I had not.

In terms of how to start this one, I really don't have much intuition here. I'm assuming that $O(h^2)$ would be $|g(h)| < Mh^2$, but I can't be sure because I'm not sure if the $h$ does something different when it is squared in that notation.

To add to my confusion here, the relation for $O(h)$ is an inequality, but it would have to become an equal sign in $o(h)$ to make this true. So I'm really not sure how these two would relate. I'm not even convinced it's true right now. Can anyone shed some light on this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definitions don't cover the full thing.

Assume that we are dealing with a limit $x\to\xi\ $ ($\xi=\infty$ allowed), and that there is a well understood function $p(x)>0$, defined in the neighborhood of $\xi$.

We furthermore have a not so well understood function $x\mapsto g(x)$, and we want to express that $g$ behaves asymptotically in a certain way when $x\to\xi$. Landau's symbols allow the following two declarations:

$$g(x)=o\bigl(p(x)\bigr)\quad(x\to\xi)\qquad:\Leftrightarrow\qquad \lim_{x\to\xi}{g(x)\over p(x)}=0\ .$$
$$g(x)=O\bigl(p(x)\bigr)\quad(x\to\xi)\qquad:\Leftrightarrow\qquad \exists M>0 \quad {\rm such \ that}\quad |g(x)|\leq M p(x)\quad\bigl(x\ {\rm near}\ \xi\bigr)\ .$$
Now, when $$g(h)=O(h^2)\quad(h\to0)\ ,$$
then there is an $M>0$ and a $h_0>0$ such that
$$|g(h)|<M h^2\quad\bigl(|h|<h_0\bigr)\ .$$
This implies
$${|g(h)|\over|h|}<M\,|h|\qquad(|h|<h_0)\ ,$$
and therefore $\ \lim_{h\to0}{|g(h)|\over|h|}=0$, and this is $\>g(h)=o(h)$ $(h\to0)$.

Comment: I see. I was definitely missing a lot of background. The definitions I wrote were just what he had on the paper, but he assumed we had seen it before. This definitely clarifies a lot. Thank you!